# Java Http Client - No Such Field Error

Tags: java, server, httpclient, nosuchfieldexception

I am trying to use the Digital Ocean java library and when trying to create a connection with:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

client = new DigitalOceanClient("v2", token, httpClient);
```

The problem lies in the `CloseableHttpClient httpClient` object. The library uses httpcore version 4.4.1 and httpclient version 4.5. It gives me a java.lang.NoSuchFieldError.

Here's my log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:955)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
at main.java.servers.DigitalOceanServer.setup(DigitalOceanServer.java:28)
```

I found little information and documentation on the NoSuchFieldError, so I'm assuming it has to do with the version of httpcore and/or httpclient that causes this error.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The field variable `INSTANCE` has been introduced in AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java since Apache httpclient version 4.4.

- [AllowAllHostnameVerifier of version
  4.3.6](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.6/src-html/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.html)
- [AllowAllHostnameVerifier of version
  4.4.0](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4/src-html/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.html)
- [SSLConnectionSocketFactory of version
  4.3.6](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.6/src-html/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html)
- [SSLConnectionSocketFactory of version 4.4.0](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4/src-html/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html)

If both new version of `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` and old version of `AllowAllHostnameVerifier` is used, then `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE` is thrown.

One of the possible cause is two version of Apache httpclient jar are in your library directory.